# Angular 2 forms dynamic id and for attributes

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a problem creating a link between the `label` and `input` element in angular with `for` and `id` attributes. Given the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
<label [attr.for]="identifier">{{label}}</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="model" [attr.id]="identifier">
  `,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() identifier: string;
}
```

What I want is **to be able to focus the input field by clicking the label**, which is the default behavior in web. This behavior works if I set the attributes statically. Or if I manually update the attributes in DOM from developer tools.

What I have tried, for both `id` and `for`:

```
id="{{identifier}}"
[id]="identifier"
[attr.id]="identifier"
```

UPDATE

Found out the problem. Check the answer below.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need the input first then the label. You can then set their style in css, but html does not render the input at the time you set the for id.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, and puts them visually the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the problem was how the input was bound where the component was used. So given the component in the question the following doesn't work:

```
<hello id="hello"></hello>
```

But instead the input has to be bound with brackets:

```
<hello [id]="'hello'"></hello>
```

Seems that this is because the conflict with native id attribute. If I rename the input to something else the first style also works.

```
<hello identifier="hello"></hello>

@Input() identfier: string;
```

Answer (score 7):

It does work. Check out the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urdzp3). You might be missing the correct property values in your component class.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  id = 'hello';
  label = 'hello';
  model = 'one';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<label [attr.for]="id">{{label}}</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="model" [attr.id]="id">
```

Comment: I forgot the mention that the id variable is an angular component input. The example you gave does work. I edited the original question.

Comment: It does not change anything. Just decorate the id property with an `@Input` decorator. `[attr.for]` and `[attr.id]` are property binding so angular will update them accordingly.

Comment: @AnttiVäyrynen I've updated the demo to use `@Input` id and it still works just fine. Take a look.

Comment: Found out the problem, check my own answer.